# Creating metadata in client org

Tags: visualforce, metadata-api, metadata, crud

I have some packaged code that utilizes the SF Metadata API to create VF pages, as well as modify some object metadata. The code currently is not executing on the client side (but it's working fine in my dev org).

How can I go about creating/editing metadata in a client org via my packaged code? I'm using the JSforce library, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully you have good error handling in your code, and if you make a support request to Salesforce you can get detailed logging enabled for your managed package in the org it is installed into and diagnose that way.

A common problem area after packaging is the namespace prefix that packaging introduces. Presumably your Metadata API calls need to create non-namespaced components (as I assume trying to create namespaced ones would be blocked), but packaged code may be implicitly adding namespace prefixes to its calls. That is the first area I would look at.

Comment: It was indeed due to package vs client namespacing. Thanks for the guidance!